# Android Popup Window vs Android Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, popupwindow

I am trying to implement a simple logic in my application where the user is shown a popup (after sometime of application launch). The popup simply shows a `TextView` with some info message. This message is refreshed every time the application is launched and a new message is shown.
The UI of the popup matches my application UI - here maybe just popup background images is needed. Also one close button (X) is shown at the top right corner of the popup - to close this popup.

**Logic of Showing Message:** I have a `String` array having some 100 strings stored in it. I randomly pick one string from this array and populate the popup `TextView` showing the message. Please suggest if there is any better approach than what I am doing already here. Also is it possible to logic that if one message is picked then the same message is not picked until the other messages are shown at least once?

**Logic of Showing Popup:** This is what I am not able to implement. I do not want to anchor the popup with any user `Event` or `Button` click. I simply wants to show the message after some time - say

> Thread.sleep(3000);

Now I have tried to use `PopupWindow` for this using the below code.

```
PopupWindow infoPopup;    
LinearLayout infoLayout;
TextView infoTextView;
Button infoButton;
infoTextView = new TextView(this);
infoTextView.setText("Testing Popup Text");
infoTextView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
infoButton = new Button(this);
infoButton.setText("Close");    
infoLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
infoLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
infoLayout.addView(infoTextView);
infoLayout.addView(infoButton);    
infoPopup = new PopupWindow(infoLayout,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
infoPopup.setContentView(infoLayout);    
try {
Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}    
infoPopup.showAtLocation((CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content),Gravity.CENTER,100,100);
```

But this popup is showing error at the last line giving null pointer on my

> (CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content)

parameter.

**The issue that I am getting are:**

1. First of all, I am not sure if this is the right approach of showing a custom UI popup. I am aware of `AlertDialog` but not sure which is the best option to go in this case - Please suggest.
2. Why the `CoordinatorLayout` is showing null pointer?
3. How to implement the top right (X) button logic in this Popup ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** Yes there are so many options for showing a custom UI popup in Android. You might select one from `PopupWindow`, `AlertDialog` or Dialog `Activity`. You need to decide which suits you best.

If you need to customize your UI a lot and have to show a list or some complex GUI then I would suggest you launch an `Activity` with `theme.Dialog`. Just set the theme of the `Activity` to something like this `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"`. There's a plenty of tutorials for implementing a dialog `Activity`.

`PopupWindow` is another tool to customize your custom pop up anywhere in the screen. If you're showing this popup always in the middle of the screen, then I would like to suggest not to use this. The `AlertDialog` should work fine.

`AlertDialog` has many variants and as far as I can assume your problem, this one suits you best. You can have a cross button too in the top-right corner of the dialog (You can set the icons anywhere, as you can provide a custom layout to an `AlertDialog`). Personally I use this [library](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) to provide a custom layout to my `AlertDialog`. You can have a look at this too.

**2.** The `NullPointerException` is simple. Your layout doesn't have any id named `main_content`. Post your logcat if this doesn't solve your problem. Post the layout too.

**3.** As I've told you earlier, I use the library to provide a custom layout to an `AlertDialog` and you can have a look at it too. So after implementing this library you can easily design your own layout with a cross button and implement the `onClick` functionalities easily.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Reaz. I shall work on your advice. I personally like the Dialog Activity you suggested but going with AlertDialog with cutom git library is also not a bad idea. I shall  mark your reply as answer once I apply it. Also there is a main_content layout in my layout file. It was just not picking it. I am working to find the resolution. Will post the logcat and solution if I find it! Thanks again!

Comment: I finally ended up using a custom dialog for this functionality. It worked!

Comment: Great to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

1. Activity with theme Dialog.
    
   This is not a good idea. It looks like a pop-up, but you can't click outside the pop-up to close it.
2. PopupWindow
    
   It will stop the application. When the user finish clicking the pop-up, the application can work again.
3. AlertDialog
    
   The best one, it will not stop the application and can be closed by clicking outside the dialog.