# PopupWindow or Dialog?

Tags: android, filter, dialog, popupwindow, android-optionsmenu

I want to show a custom Filtering Menu when clicking an item/action's icon from the `OptionsMenu`, and I was wondering how shall I do it, either navigating to a `DialogFragment` or showing a `PopupWindow` and place any of them on the right side of the screen.

Any other better option is also welcome :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `PopUp` option, either you can create a custom one (or using [`ListPopupWindow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ListPopupWindow) or using for instance the [`PowerMenu`](https://github.com/skydoves/PowerMenu) library.

But it depends the UI you have in mind, the design you shared perhaps is multi-selector option, also there's the button of *apply* changes, where in `PopUpWindow` it's with a click, and also the *reset filter* button there in the same filter.

To know better the difference between them read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38740000/4385913) it might help you which way you should take.

Comment: I finally decided to implement a DialogFragment and set the gravity on the right. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by custom Filtering Menu?

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see any button for adding comments